# Read printer pool to get number of pages being printed

Tags: c#, vb.net, printing

I have a network printer in the classroom lab. I'd like to keep record of how many pages of each student has printed. I want to know how can I read
the printer pool to get the number of pages, when a student prints. Here's what I have in mind: Write a Windows service to get:

1. User logged in name
2. Number of printed everytime they print the docs
3. Send username + number of pages to remote database

What I don't know:

1. how to get number of pages every time they print

If possible I'd like to see this done in VB.NET.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WMI class [Win32_PrintJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get out information about each job. It has properties called `PagesPrinted` and `TotalPages` which would hopefully give you what you need. It also has other properties like `Status` that might also be relevant (if you don't want to count pages in deleted or failed jobs or similar).

This article has information about calling this class from VB.Net:
[Interrogating your Printer Queries with WMI](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/jodonnell/PrinterQueries04202005005917AM/PrinterQueries.aspx)

Just remember to add a reference to `System.Management` since that's not added by default to a new project.

Comment: @Azarsa It's been a while so I can't remember, but I'd assume that it should work the same way. As long as the printer driver has been installed, I would have thought it would would look the same to the WMI classes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if a remote machine send a print command to the local computer that the printer hosts, then on remote machine TotalPages are zero!. I think I should use Sockets, shouldn't I? Both systems use WMI class.

Comment: @Azarsa You can use WMI to query a remote computer, look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290(v=vs.85).aspx